# How to check with function if table_2 anywhere contains X,Y,Z values from table_1?

Tags: excel

There are two tables and both contain values XYZ.
How to check if second table contains exact coordinates in all values.

```
`First Table:`
111, 222, 333
122, 123, 111
`Second Table:`
125, 111, 156
111, 222, 333
```

So, second table contains all 3 values from first one(row doesn't matter) and should return true.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to  do this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table2[X],Table1[X],Table2[Y],Table1[Y],Table2[Z],Table1[Z]))
```

assuming these are two actual tables as below.

[image]

I have tested this in Microsoft 365 - you may need to use Sumproduct or enter as an array formula in lower versions of Excel.

Comment: Thank you! That's it!